# Using different data types for the same method

Tags: java, methods

I want to use double values and int values separately in one method as parameters of the method how can I achieve that? The method is multiplying two integer numbers and two double numbers in the same method. The output should be two lines one for the integer and the other for the double value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way would be to overload the method :

```
void foo(int i)
void foo(double i)
```

But it is also valid to assign an `int` to a `double`, so you could also provide only :

```
void foo(double i)
```

to accept both `int` and `double`.

An alternative to overloading would be to define a generic class with a method that accepts the generic type :

```
public class Bar<T extends Number>{
   public void foo(T t){
      ...
   }
}
```

And you could so instantiate them :

```
Bar<Integer> barInt = new Bar<>();
barInt .foo(3);
Bar<Double> barDouble = new Bar<>();
barDouble.foo(3);
```

Note that numeric wrappers consume more memory as primitive counter parts.
So the first way with overloading is really the most efficient.

And you have still many other ways to handle this question.
All that to say that you should use a way or another according your requirement.

Comment: This would be the best practice, but for only one method it is a way to much effort.

Comment: @LenglBoy  . Overloading is more efficient in any case but generics could make more sense according to the use case. The question is probably too broad.

Comment: Can you explain what overloading is with more example?

Answer (score 0):

For some calculation which are typesafe for int/double you can just use this:

```
<T> T calc(T a, Tb) { };
```

If you want to use functions for a special Type (rounding/floating behaviour/...) you can use `instance of` and call a help method with `INT` or `DOUBLE` or ... or just do it in `if-else`.